# Related to cellID

Tags: android

I have written the following code to get cellsite id in mobile app, and i'm able to get the id only if mobile gps is on else id will be null or blank.
I need to know why i have to turn on gps to get cell id.
The code is as follows.

***My code -***

```
public double getCellsiteID(){

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    double cid = 0;
    if (telephony.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
        final GsmCellLocation location = (GsmCellLocation) telephony
                .getCellLocation();
        if (location != null) {

            cid = location.getCid();
        }
    }
    return cid;
}
```

Thank you.